# NullPointerException in JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I am reading from a JSON ReST API. And the JSON looks different
The first looks like this :

```
processJSON({
  "TripList":{
  "noNamespaceSchemaLocation":"http://api.vasttrafik.se/v1/hafasRestTrip.xsd",
  "servertime":"10:39",
  "serverdate":"2013-04-04",
  "Trip":[{
    "Leg":[{
      "name":"Buss 761",
      "type":"BUS",
      "id":"9015014576100035",
      "direction":"Heden via Linnéplatsen",
      "fgColor":"#00A5DC",
      "bgColor":"#ffffff",
      "stroke":"Solid",
      "Origin":{
        "name":"Hökegårdsgatan, Mölndal",
        "type":"ST",
        "id":"9022014012273002",
        "routeIdx":"30",
        "time":"10:42",
        "date":"2013-04-04",
        "track":"B ",
        "$":"\n"
        }
```

the second like this :

```
processJSON({
"TripList":{
  "noNamespaceSchemaLocation":"http://api.vasttrafik.se/v1/hafasRestTrip.xsd",
  "servertime":"10:46",
  "serverdate":"2013-04-04",
  "Trip":[{
    "Leg":{
      "name":"Spårvagn 8",
      "type":"TRAM",
      "id":"9015014500800075",
      "direction":"Angered",
      "fgColor":"#872387",
      "bgColor":"#ffffff",
      "stroke":"Solid",
      "accessibility":"wheelChair",
      "Origin":{
        "name":"Korsvägen, Göteborg",
        "type":"ST",
        "id":"9022014003980005",
        "routeIdx":"12",
        "time":"10:50",
        "date":"2013-04-04",
        "track":"E ",
        "rtTime":"10:51",
        "rtDate":"2013-04-04",
        "$":"\n"
        }
```

Now what I wanna do is if the JSON "Leg" is an Array I loop into the Array and get the data.
But if the "Leg" is an object there is no use to loop I can just dig and get the data.
This one is working for me

But the first is not working and gives an nullpointerexpection.

#### My code is :

```
public class ParseTimeTable {

String temp = "";

public void parseJsonData() throws ParseException, IOException {

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = parser.parse(Planner.getPlanner().getJsonDataForTrip(
            Planner.getPlanner().getStartLocationID(),
            Planner.getPlanner().getDestinationID()));
    JSONObject topObject = (JSONObject) obj;
    JSONObject tripList = (JSONObject) topObject.get("TripList");
    JSONArray array = (JSONArray) tripList.get("Trip");
    Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = array.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

        JSONObject jsonObj = iterator.next();

        if (jsonObj.get("Leg") instanceof JSONArray)

        {

            JSONArray array2 = (JSONArray) tripList.get("Leg");
            Iterator<JSONObject> iterator2 = array2.iterator();
            while (iterator2.hasNext()) {

                String line = (String) jsonObj.get("name");
                String direction = (String) jsonObj.get("direction");
                JSONObject origin = (JSONObject) jsonObj.get("Origin");
                String name = (String) origin.get("name");
                String time = (String) origin.get("time");
                String track = (String) origin.get("track");

                JSONObject destination = (JSONObject) jsonObj.get("Destination");
                String dname = (String) destination.get("name");
                String dtime = (String) destination.get("time");
                String dtrack = (String) destination.get("track");

                temp = line + " " + "Mot : " + direction + " " + "Från : "
                        + name + " " + "Avgång : " + time + " "
                        + "Track : " + track + "- " + "Destination : "
                        + dname + " " + "Ankomst : " + dtime + " "
                        + "Track : " + dtrack;

                TripService.getTrip().setList(temp);

            }

        }

        else {

            jsonObj = (JSONObject) jsonObj.get("Leg");
            String line = (String) jsonObj.get("name");
            String direction = (String) jsonObj.get("direction");
            JSONObject origin = (JSONObject) jsonObj.get("Origin");
            String name = (String) origin.get("name");
            String time = (String) origin.get("time");
            String track = (String) origin.get("track");

            JSONObject destination = (JSONObject)                           jsonObj.get("Destination");
            String dname = (String) destination.get("name");
            String dtime = (String) destination.get("time");
            String dtrack = (String) destination.get("track");

            temp = line + " " + "Mot : " + direction + " " + "Från : "
                    + name + " " + "Avgång : " + time + " " + "Track : "
                    + track + "- " + "Destination : " + dname + " "
                    + "Ankomst : " + dtime + " " + "Track : " + dtrack;

            TripService.getTrip().setList(temp);

        }

    }

}
```

}

So everything in my else statement is working like it should but in my if statement I get a nullpointer because the array2 is empty..
So what is giving me a nullpointer is my second Array : JSONArray array2 = (JSONArray) tripList.get("Leg");

#### Why is it so?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at se.lowdin.trafficPlanner.ParseTimeTable.parseJsonData(ParseTimeTable.java:35)
    at se.lowdin.trafficPlanner.MainWindow$UpdateAction.actionPerformed(MainWindow.java:294)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: please show stack trace

Comment: Which line is #35 exactly?

Comment: the json is not valid please check the json with http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Josef - are you using the GWT JSON library? If so, what version?

Answer (score 1):

In your "if" statement, you are checking the type of *jsonObj*.get(), but you are assigning the value of *tripList*.get() to your array.

I think you mean:

```
JSONArray array2 = (JSONArray) jsonObj.get("Leg");
```

Comment: That defies all logic... if `jsonObj.get("Leg") instanceOf JSONArray` is true, then `JSONArray array2 = (JSONArray) jsonObj.get("Leg")` would not be assigning NULL...

Comment: Have you tried `JSONArray array2 = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Leg")` ?

Comment: @Josef - are you sure that each `Trip` is guaranteed to have a `Leg` element? In other words, if `trip.get("Leg")` can ever return null, then you *will* get an NPE. It's probably best to code defensively against that, even if its not happening with your test data right now.

Answer (score 0):

`TripList` doesn't contain `Leg`.

In this line:

```
JSONArray array2 = (JSONArray) tripList.get("Leg");
```

You try to get "Leg" from "TripList", which **doesn't have one**.

Try using:

```
JSONArray array2 = (JSONArray) jsonObj.get("Leg");
```